# Data does not appear in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a simple form that allows you to select users and select a hospital. The form successfully submits. However when I view the index.html.erb, it looks like the following: [imgur][1]. Any idea why the "Full name" and "Hospital" is not appearing?

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :booking_reference %>
      <br/>
      <%= f.text_field :booking_reference %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= fields_for :User do |user| %>
          <%= user.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :full_name %>

      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= fields_for :hospital do |hosp| %>
          <%= hosp.collection_select :hospital_id, Hospital.all, :id, :name %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't that be like

```
<div class="field">
      <%=  f.collection_select :hospital_id, Hospital.all, :id, :name %>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="field">
      <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :full_name %>
</div>
```

?

Otherwise you break the form helper.

In doubt, check the api here: [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)

Comment: I've checked this out already. If I am to do it that way I get the following error 
`NoMethodError in Hospital_bookings#new undefined method user_id' for #<HospitalBooking:0x2bd6778>`

Comment: Does the HospitalBookings model have an attribute user_id?

Comment: I updated my question and added the HospitalBooking model and yes it does

Comment: Because the statement says: Uh now comes a field for HospitalBooking - it is named hospital_id, you can get the list for the drop down form Hospital model and you should use the field id for inserting, but show the field name for the select box. (and analog for the user model)

Comment: Do you need a  attr_accessible :user_id, too? I am unsure.

Comment: So are you essentially saying that I should do something like: `<%= f.collection_select :hospital_id, User.all, :user_id, :full_name %>`

Comment: Updated the answer to contain both parts.

Comment: It turned out that the migration for HospitalBooking was missing the field for the related table keys.